# How do I push messages to a phone app over the internet, quickly?

Tags: android, sockets, push-notification

I want to send instant messages to users of my phone app over the internet with no more than a one second delay (or two at very worst).

Should I have the phone app continually make requests to the server? Which type of request?

Should the phone app hold a socket connection open to the server?

What's the common/standard technique? How does Whatsapp do it?

Comment: Have a look at Google Cloud Messaging. That is much more battery-friendly than a socket or even polling the server every second

Comment: How does GCM work? I've read it has delays.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/. While the app is opened, you can hold a socket. But please don't do that while your app is in background...

Comment: It sounds like GCM holds a socket.

Comment: I think so, but it holds one single socket for all apps, eg WhatsApp, Signal, ...

Answer (score 1):

What you should be looking for is **XMPP** ([Extensible Message and Presence Protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMPP))

The Extensible Messaging and Presence Protocol (XMPP) is an open technology for real-time communication, using the Extensible Markup Language (XML) as the base format for exchanging information. In essence, XMPP provides a way to send small pieces of XML from one entity to another in close to real time.
It efficiently allows you to:

- Channel Encryption
- One-to-one messaging
- Multi-party messaging
- Notifications

And so on! More info is available [here](http://xmpp.org/)

Now coming to the answer of your question, I am assuming you are creating a chatting application! Which can be implemented using the GCM XMPP. A nice tutorial is available [here](http://javapapers.com/android/android-chat-with-google-gcm-xmpp/). Also there exists many libraries to make the process swift and secure. [[This]](https://github.com/siacs/Conversations). Also you can use 3rd party API which makes use of `XMPP` to achieve your goal! See [this](http://www.tutorialsface.com/2015/08/building-your-own-android-chat-messenger-app-similar-to-whatsapp-using-xmpp-smack-4-1-api-from-scratch-part-2/). Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

If that's the requirement (1 or 2 sec), then you should use socket. As it is much faster than GCM and control would be in your hands. You must take care of battery.